# Meta Box value not been pulled in

Tags: functions, metabox

Here is the code that creates my metabox on my CPT named clients it displays fine and seems to keep the value input upon clicking update. The problem is with displaying the value saved within the metabox on a page.

I've tried outputting the data both within a loop and out the loop switching between `get_the_ID() and $post_id`

I've tried debugging with `<?php var_dump($link); ?>` which displays this on the frontend `string(0) ""`

To output the meta box value in the loop I'm doing

```
// Get Meta data
$link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link_url', true); ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('clients'); ?></a></li>
```

Meta box Code

```
/**
     * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
     */
    function portfolio_link_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'clients' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'portfolio_logo_link',
            __( 'Logo Link', 'logo_link_textdomain' ),
            'logo_link_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'portfolio_link_add_meta_box' );

function logo_link_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'logo_link_meta_box', 'logo_link_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link_url', true );

    echo '<label for="link">';
    _e( 'Add The Logo Link', 'link_logo_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="link" name="link" value="' . $value . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function logo_link_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['logo_link_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['logo_link_meta_box_nonce'], 'logo_link_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['link'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['link'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link_url', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'logo_link_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Comment: What does your `var_dump` show? Besides the text/link inside the `href` of an `a` tag won't visibly displayed.

Comment: I've been looking in inspect element after putting the word "test" in the metabox it should appear between the href tags. But as you can see nothing appears.

Comment: But the `get_post_meta` in your callback works? Does `get_the_ID` return an ID?

Comment: Here, `$link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link_url', true);` Make sure you are getting proper id and first check is really your value stored in database post_meta table.

Comment: How Can I check I'm getting the correct id?

Comment: I've just checked if the value's are saved in the db and they all are but under a metakey of _my_meta_value_key - I've changed this to 'link_url' however its saved in the DB with its old name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom post type slug is clients in 
    $screens = array( 'clients' );

Because i have just tested your code in local and its working fine.

Comment: Hi @Shail, The problem is with outputting the value saved within the metabox. Updated my question

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem? You can't get value on front side?

Comment: Yes Shail, I cannot get the value to output.